Working as a computer scientist with a research focus purely in pure mathematics
I'm aiming to work in a computer science department after getting a PhD in computer science on theoretical computer science research, but my research interest/trajectory will be focused on solving a problem in theoretical computer science of which it's resolution falls entirely within the realm of pure mathematics(representation theory). This approach would have me publishing primarily in mathematics journals, presenting at mathematics conferences, and collaborating closely with the mathematics community rather than the traditional computer science one.
I'm wondering:
How common or advisable is this path, where your research as a computer scientist will be indistinguishable from pure mathematics research?
Could this impact my prospects for a career in computer science, especially if I aim for roles in CS departments?
What are the unique challenges associated with pursuing a CS PhD with a focus so deeply rooted in mathematics?

For what it's worth, there is a well-known approach to P=NP using representation theory of complex semisimple Lie groups (branching rules). However, so far, nobody was able to make it work, it is a hard problem. :)

This is an answer from a US mathematician whose work is occasionally not so far from computer science (and who regularly teaches the automata theory course for the computer science department, being the closest thing to a theoretical computer scientist on campus).  The purpose of this disclaimer is to give you some indication of how I could be wrong.
Hiring and tenure at research universities is far more grant-driven in computer science than in mathematics.  At a research university, a computer scientist is generally expected to bring in substantial grant funding, whereas the expectations for mathematicians are generally much less.  There is much less grant funding available in theoretical mathematics (as well as in theoretical areas of computer science) than in directly applicable computer science (or applied math).  This means you may be held to standards that you are simply unable to meet.  Indeed, most lower-ranked research universities (like mine) have very few or no theoretical computer scientists, because they expect their computer scientists to get substantial grants, and the relatively smaller amount of funding in theoretical computer science all goes to a few researchers who are all at better-ranked departments.  (Also, they expect their computer scientists to have grad students, and it can be quite difficult to recruit students capable of making contributions to theory at a lower-ranked university.)
That being said, there are also a lot of mathematics PhDs competing for not many professorships in mathematics, and it's not clear your job prospects will be better as a mathematician.  (I have said before that, if you are looking for a research-oriented job in mathematics in the middle of the next recession, whenever that is, you might have to be at least a longshot potential Fields Medalist to get one.) Just be aware that your job prospects in academia will be worse than prospects in other areas of computer science.  I can certainly see that you might find teaching introductory programming more interesting than teaching calculus (though you should be prepared to figure out ways to pass students who cannot figure out how to write a program on their own, just as mathematicians have to pass calculus students who can only do problems by blindly memorizing solutions to problems they have seen).

Also worth thinking about: What's your fallback if your line of research gets completely stuck (for you individually or for the community as a whole), or worse yet, if it's killed off (say by relativization results)?  Would you move to neighboring areas of math or neighboring areas of CS?  Try to move to primarily teaching or administrative roles?  Quit academia and research and work as a programmer?

I don't think the comparison to "longshot potential Fields Medalist" is useful. The number of longshot Fields Medalists is vastly smaller than the number of math faculty positions at R1 universities, even in bad years. Furthermore, the list of longshot potential Fields Medalists includes approximately zero applied mathematicians, whereas ~50% of open positions are in applied mathematics.

@WolfgangBangerth: I really think the next bad year will be that bad, with only a literal handful of positions open to theoretical mathematicians.  Those applied mathematicians who can apply for NIH money will do better.

This makes no sense. There are perhaps 100 R1 universities in the US alone, with perhaps 4000 math professors. To replace retirements, there are a steady state of at least 100 positions per year, or 400 positions per Fields Medal cycle. Across the countries that can reasonably compete for Fields Medalists, that is surely >1000 positions per Fields Medal cycle, and that must doubtlessly be vastly more than the number of people on the Fields Medal shortlist, even if one took into account that during bad years that number of positions might be substantially smaller.

I will also point out that the number of applied mathematicians who have NIH money is a relatively small fraction of all applied mathematicians.

@WolfgangBangerth: I anticipate that my department and many like it will never again hire a theoretical mathematician.  Most retirements in theoretical mathematics will not be replaced.  Many universities no longer have Classics departments and only have two or three Philosophy faculty.  English departments now usually have many non-tenure-track faculty teaching general education writing courses (coordinated by a non-tenure-track director of writing), with only a handful of faculty doing research in literature.  Theoretical mathematics is going in the same direction.

I don't doubt that there are departments that are phasing out pure mathematicians, but it's not what's happening at most R1 universities.

@AlexanderWoo huh, that's news to me. But I guess like Wolfgang said, perhaps there are different trends in different unis

I don't know how common it is currently, but in the past it was quite common. I'd guess that you could make it work as long as you can deal with the required teaching and advising in CS. It might also give you an opening into a math department.
Lots of parts of CS are very mathematical, in a theoretical, not just computational sense. And note that a lot of collaboration in many fields, inducing CS, is done with people outside the immediate department. If you publish, it will be respected.
It could also be an advantage at many universities to foster collaborations between the CS and math departments. The last place I worked had too little of that I thought. All of my own collaborations, and they were many, were with people at other institutions, many in other countries, many of them mathematicians as was my own background.
And, don't imaging that this current project will be your last one. Depending on how it goes and how you manage to fit in to a CS department collaborating with mathematicians, you might move focus in either direction.

The other two answers here are excellent and give you a viewpoint from relatively more senior people. Like Alexander, I'm at a lower-ranked R1/R2 borderline math department (we'll be R1 after January upcoming). My specialty is somewhere in computational mathematics, so in this sense intersects heavily with chunks of the theoretical side of CS.  I've been on the job market in the last two years, and think it's worth providing some perspective on that.
The publication culture in computer science is largely distinct from the traditional cadence of mathematicians and theoretical computer scientists. Most CS professors publish a larger number of shorter papers. Many of those go into conference proceedings rather than traditional journals.
Theory-focused research programs don't mesh incredibly well with that cadence. At the extreme end, if you don't diversify a bit to include several conference proceedings papers during your PhD, it seems from my anecdotal experience that most CS departments will not really know what to do with your tenure-track application. Perhaps you'll have 3 journal articles or so in review or published by the end of a PhD. If they are very high quality, maybe one of the higher ranked CS departments could appreciate them. If not, then you'll be competing with applicants who on paper have some order-of-10+ or whatever number of conference proceedings.
I say this from at least some experience. Last time around, I threw in a few applications to CS departments angling as a type of very theoretical computer scientist. None of those got much traction, and it seemed to be for the reason above. Think of it another way: CS departments process quite a number of graduate students these days. Those students need projects. Many of them need the projects to run on relatively short schedules and entail software experience because the students are not aiming for an academic career.
How are you going to show the CS departments to which you apply that you're going to be able to fit into that schema effectively? It's not impossible by any stretch. I have colleagues in CS departments who pull this off. But if your goal is to get a tenure-track job at a research-focused CS department with a theoretically-inclined program, I'd encourage you to be strategic. Yes, write some theory during your PhD. But be willing to sacrifice some of that theory for a number of quick and more applied conference papers. Trying to figure out this balance seems to be one of the unique challenges of this theoretical CS/computational math space.

Theoretical computer science has its own conferences - SODA, FOCS, et c - publishing in those can work.  However, you do bring up an important point, because if OP is planning to work in geometric complexity theory as I'm guessing, then even these conferences aren't good venues for their work.

@AlexanderWoo Right. Hopefully my answer gets across-- I'm not trying to say that there aren't appropriate venues available. Just that the classic theorist's approach of publishing some smaller number of more detailed papers largely doesn't seem to work to land a CS job without some adjustment.
