Considering a Program Switch
I'm currently in my 4th year of a CS PhD program in the US. I've completed most of the program requirements (coursework and qualifiers), so now it's just my thesis remaining. My work is about 80% Math and 20% CS, and my advisor is from the Math department, though she has a courtesy appointment in CS. When I started working with her last year, she suggested I take some Math courses to support my research, which led me to realize that I enjoy the Math aspect of my work more than the CS side.
In fact, I've come to prefer the Math culture over the CS culture at my university, and I find myself more engaged in Math seminars than in CS ones. I also feel I'd be more comfortable as a Math faculty member if I end up in academia, particularly in teaching Math courses rather than CS.
I've been thinking about discussing this with my advisor to see if there’s a possibility of switching to the Math program while keeping her as my advisor. I realize this could add around 1-2 years to my graduation timeline, as I'd need to complete the Math department's requirements, including qualifying exams and some additional coursework (some of which I’m already considering for a master’s in Math if I stay in the CS PhD program). My goal is to pursue a career in academia, and I feel this switch could improve my chances of joining a Math department, where I believe I’d be happier.
On the other hand, I recognize the challenges of securing an academic position, and if I ultimately need to transition to industry, a CS degree might offer better job prospects.

This is too individualized for us to answer here.

I'm not in math, but from what I hear, the competition for math jobs is fierce, whereas CS is maybe a little bit better because people have industry to go to as well. I probably wouldn't move from a degree that opens more doors to once that's less for the cost of 1-2 years.

As a follow-up to @AzorAhai-him- 's point, I answered a different but related question recently that I think contains relevant information for you. Long story short, as a strategic matter, it seems to be a lot more lucrative to have CS credentials as a theorist than math if you're at this intersection. Yes, you may have to resign yourself to teaching CS-type courses for undergrads. But that's just as likely to happen in a math dept. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/214545/working-as-a-computer-scientist-with-a-research-focus-purely-in-pure-mathematics/214628#214628

See also our canonical question on switching fields post-PhD (which, IMO, is a better idea than switching during the 4th year of PhD).

What’s your actual question? It looks like you are only describing your situation, not asking anything.

Let me suggest an alternative that will, perhaps, get you started earlier, but to the same place, more or less using those two years.  Just something to ponder.
There are certainly parts of CS that are a lot like math, in theory and in practice; similar methodology. You seem to be in a good place with a good advisor at the moment.
Suppose that you focus in your dissertation research with this advisor on one of those "mathy" aspects of CS, finish the degree and find a job in a department that values theoretical work.
Suppose that you keep in contact with this advisor after completion, and become her collaborator on something even more along the lines of math. A background in CS might be helpful in some aspects of math just as math is helpful in parts of CS.
I don't think you need a MS in math to take this route but it will take some study. Your current advisor might be a good guide for that.
There is no reason why your career can't take a turn.
You don't seem to be absolutely driven to math with no other mental options, as many of us were. We often say "You don't choose math. Math chooses you." Unless that is truly the case, some flexibility in the early career with a press toward a wider goal might be a good move. It won't work if math has truly "captured" you, but it might otherwise.
Some but not all universities have math and CS departments that interact with one another. Someone with a foot in both camps can be an asset.
Of course, you should follow a dream, knowing something of the consequences. As noted in comments the market for mathematicians is pretty tight at present.
My career was in the opposite direction. I was "driven out" of math by an extremely unfavorable marketplace and switched to CS with self study. I was comfortable there, both with the more and the less theoretical aspects. Oddly enough, one of the authors of the first book I chose to study programming (a luminary) later wound up  as a student in a short course I gave at a CS conference. Quite a coincidence.
